# 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found

Tags: spring, security, basic-authentication, userdetailsservice

I am using spring security basic authentication where I'm getting the below error while application startup:

Parameter 2 of method authManager in com.spring.security.firstapp.security.MySecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration.

### MySecurityConfig.java

@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfig {

```
@Autowired
private MyAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
        UserDetailsService userDetailService) throws Exception {
    return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    return http.build();

}



@Bean
public static BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

### MyAuthenticationProvider.java

@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    String userName = authentication.getName();
    String passWord = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    
    if("tom".equals(userName) && "abc".equals(passWord))
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, passWord);
    else
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials!!");
    
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

### Controller

@RestController
public class HelloController {

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello() {
    return "Spring Boot Security";
}
```

}

### pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.4
 

com.first-app
spring-security
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
spring-security
spring-security

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-security


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added bean on class **MySecurityConfig**

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    UserDetails user = User.withUsername("user")
        .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
        .roles("USER")
        .build();

    UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("admin")
        .password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin"))
        .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
        .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
}
```

After it run good.